# Elasticsearch one field match different values

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to do a query, with one field match different values,In SQL it likes:

`select * from location where address like '%California%' and address like '%145%';`

I tried using must condition array, it contains several phrase match conditions, but its doesnt work!

```html
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 10,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [ {
            "match" : {
              "address" : {
                "query" : "California",
                "type" : "phrase"
              }
            }
          }, {
            "match" : {
              "address" : {
                "query" : "145",
                "type" : "phrase"
              }
            }
          } ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort" : [ {
    "pageRankScore" : {
      "order" : "desc",
      "unmapped_type" : "double"
    }
  } ]
}
```

Thats my code, it only do a match '145', never match 'California'.

My question is: with several values, how to do a fuzzy match in one field?

Help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you show a sample document that should match your query?

Comment: Sorry, there is no document, I just want the field 'address' which can match two values 'California' and '145' at the same time.but not exactly match, more like a fuzzy match.

Comment: You said that your query never matches, can you show a document that you want the query to match? i.e. how can you know it doesn't match if there's no document?